# Directive template does not show in view

Tags: angularjs

I try to make my first directive and I use this page to get started: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

The directive seems to be loaded but the element it should create in my view does not show.

My app.module.js

```
// script.js

// create the module and name it mainApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'chart.js']);

// configure our routes
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/first', {
            templateUrl : 'views/firstView.html',
            controller  : 'firstController'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl : 'views/secondView.html',
            controller  : 'secondController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/third', {
            templateUrl : 'views/thirdView.html',
            controller  : 'thirdController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/fourth', {
            templateUrl : 'views/fourthView.html',
            controller  : 'fourthController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/first'
        });
});
```

The secondController

```
mainApp.controller('secondController', function ($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.bericht = '2-Everyone come and see how good I look!';
})
.directive('testDirective', ['', function(){
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        // name: '',
        // priority: 1,
        // terminal: true,
        // scope: {}, // {} = isolate, true = child, false/undefined = no change
        // controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {},
        // require: 'ngModel', // Array = multiple requires, ? = optional, ^ = check parent elements
        //restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
        template: 'tralalala'
    };
}]);
```

The secondView

```
<h1>{{ bericht }}</h1>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="secondController">
    <div testDirective></div> 
</div>
```

I expect the `<div testDirective></div>` to show up as `tralalala` but it does not show at all, also no error in console.

Comment: <div testDirective> should be <div test-directive>

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is mixed up:

The directive registered as `testDirective` will look for `test-directive` in the html.

Try:

```
<div test-directive></div>
```

OR

```
<test-directive></test-directive>
```

Comment: Now it returns an error: 
Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- testDirectiveDirective

Comment: Then you must be injecting that directive name somewhere not shown. You don't inject directives as dependencies , you register them in a module

Comment: @Thijs `['', function()`should be `[function()`